# Oracle query that will select from 2 tables join on either column a or b

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, left-join

I am using Oracle 11.

I have table ca and table t.

Table ca has columns id, effective_date, othercolumn

Table t has columns id, effective_date, ledger_effective_date and value.

How do I do a query that will select from table ca join with table t on either column effective_date or ledger_effective_date ?

If I can't find a match where ca.effective_date = t.effective_date , then I want to find a match where ca.effective_date = t.ledger_effective_date.

There are other columns and tables that I join also, ID and effective date are 2 of the columns.

I use (+) for the outer join. How can I do this with (+) ?

This query doesn't work

```
(ca.effective_date = T.EFFECTIVE_DATE(+) OR ca.effective_date = T.LEDGER_EFFECTIVE_DATE(+))
```

Example data

```
ca table
id effective_date othercolumn
1  1/1/21         a
2  1/2/21         b
3  1/3/21         c
```

t table

```
id effective_date  ledger_effective_date  value
1  2/5/21          1/1/21                 100 
2  1/2/21          1/3/21                 200
3  3/3/21          3/4/21                 300
```

The desired result

```
id othercolumn  value
1  a            100
2  b            200
3  c            null
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like outer join to me as well. Something like this (sample data in lines #1 - 11; query begins at line #12):

```
SQL> with
  2  ca (id, effective_date, othercolumn) as
  3    (select 1, date '2021-01-01', 'a' from dual union all
  4     select 2, date '2021-01-02', 'b' from dual union all
  5     select 3, date '2021-01-03', 'c' from dual
  6    ),
  7  t (id, effective_date, ledger_effective_date, value) as
  8    (select 1, date '2021-05-02', date '2021-01-01', 100 from dual union all
  9     select 2, date '2021-01-02', date '2021-03-01', 200 from dual union all
 10     select 3, date '2021-03-03', date '2021-04-03', 300 from dual
 11    )
 12  select a.id, a.othercolumn, t.value
 13  from ca a left join t on a.effective_date = t.effective_date
 14                        or a.effective_date = t.ledger_effective_date;

        ID OTHERCOLUMN          VALUE
---------- --------------- ----------
         1 a                      100
         2 b                      200
         3 c

SQL>
```

---

Though, why don't you join them on `ID` column? Isn't that a better match?

Comment: Thank you. ID is one of the columns that I join them, but I also need to join by the effective_date. There are other columns and tables that I join also (the above example is a very simplify version of the real quer). I use (+) for the outer join. How can I do this with (+) ?

Comment: (+) is the "old" Oracle's outer join operator. If you use ANSI joins, then it is - as in my example **left join**. I suggest you use it.